# What is the best way to encrypt a lot of large images?

Tags: .net, encryption, jpeg, jpeg2000

I need to encrypt a lot of large JPEG files.

The pictures are very sensitive and need to only be decrypted inside my application.

Because of the number and size of the images, speed is an issue.

Comment: No, not porn. ;) Photos of patients.

Comment: @Jason What medical department?

Comment: @Aiden... a private practice for a cosmetic surgeon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really doesn't matter what format your files are - you can encrypt any byte sequence.

Read the documentation on, say, [TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.tripledescryptoserviceprovider(loband).aspx) and that will provide you with all the tools you need to encrypt anything.

Of course, if `TripleDES` is too slow for you, you can try a weaker algorithm. But, honestly, you usually trade speed for security in these matters.

Comment: AES is significatnly faster than TripleDES, generally more trusted, well analyzed and widely recommended. AES achieves speeds of 100MB/sec and it is quite hard to find anything significantly faster. Even if 100MB/sec is not enough I'd not trade security for speed. I'd rather wait for the next generation of Intel CPUs that have special instruction that support AES.